# Rails/MongoId - Concatenate multiple queries on multiple models with conditional criterias

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have three models: Culture, Nature and History.

I also have an array containing user's search criterias:

```
["nature", "culture", "history"]
```

Of course, this array might contain only one or two criteria (such as "nature and culture", or just "nature" etc.)

According to this array, I want to query the corresponding Models and render the result in an unique collection.

I've tried a lot of things, such as:

```
 @sites = Culture.where(:coordinates => {"$ne" => "", "$ne" => nil} )

if array_type_sites.include?("nature")
      @sitesNature = Nature.where(:coordinates => {"$ne" => "", "$ne" => nil} )
      @sites << @sitesNature
 end
 if array_type_sites.include?("culture")
       @sitesCulture = Culture.where(:coordinates => {"$ne" => "", "$ne" => nil} )
       @sites << @sitesCulture
end  

return @sites
```

In this code, `@sites` isn't implemented with `@sitesCulture`, only with `@sitesNature`.

What is the best way to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Inheritance in Mongoid? http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#inheritance

The following tests does what I think you want to do, with Culture, History, and Nature objects
stored and fetched from a collection with types being preserved.
I hope that you find this useful.

app/models/interest

```
class Interest
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :description, type: String
  field :coordinates, type: String
end
```

app/models/culture

```
class Culture < Interest; end
```

app/models/history

```
class History < Interest; end
```

app/models/nature

```
class Nature < Interest; end
```

test/unit/interest_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'
require 'pp'

class InterestTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    Interest.delete_all
    Culture.delete_all
    History.delete_all
    Nature.delete_all
  end

  test "version" do
    puts "\nMongoid::VERSION:#{Mongoid::VERSION}\nMoped::VERSION:#{Moped::VERSION}"
  end
  test "inheritance" do
    Culture.create(description: "a culture site", coordinates: "40.7577° N, 73.9857° W")
    History.create(description: "a history site", coordinates: "40.7577° N, 73.9857° W")
    Nature.create(description: "a nature site", coordinates: "40.7577° N, 73.9857° W")

    array_type_sites = ["nature", "culture", "history"]
    @sites = Culture.where(:coordinates => {"$ne" => "", "$ne" => nil} ).to_a

    if array_type_sites.include?("nature")
      @sitesNature = Nature.where(:coordinates => {"$ne" => "", "$ne" => nil} ).to_a
      @sites += @sitesNature
    end
    if array_type_sites.include?("culture")
      @sitesCulture = Culture.where(:coordinates => {"$ne" => "", "$ne" => nil} ).to_a
      @sites += @sitesCulture
    end

    Interest.collection.insert(@sites.collect{|site|site.serializable_hash})
    puts
    pp Interest.all.to_a
  end
end
```

rake test

```
Run options:

# Running tests:

[1/2] InterestTest#test_inheritance
[#<Culture _id: 53dfd43b7f11ba43ef000001, description: "a culture site", coordinates: "40.7577° N, 73.9857° W", _type: "Culture">,
 #<History _id: 53dfd43b7f11ba43ef000002, description: "a history site", coordinates: "40.7577° N, 73.9857° W", _type: "History">,
 #<Nature _id: 53dfd43b7f11ba43ef000003, description: "a nature site", coordinates: "40.7577° N, 73.9857° W", _type: "Nature">]
[2/2] InterestTest#test_version
Mongoid::VERSION:3.1.6
Moped::VERSION:1.5.2
Finished tests in 0.084751s, 23.5985 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
2 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips

ruby -v: ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-darwin12.0]
```